# Default chart colors Keynote showroom

Tags: keynote, color, defaults

I want to find out what are the default colors of a 3D bar chart in *Showroom* layout on keynote. When you add a new chart, you get this colors: [image]

But I was unable to find them in the colors palette.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the internals of a fresh Showroom layout Keynote file (it's a zipped folder actually). Inside, there is a `index.apxl` file which contains lots of data .. also color data. I wrote this short Ruby script to make a quick-and-dirty html file with all colors used in the Keynote document:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en-us\"><body>"
file = IO.read("index.apxl") # slurp apxl file

# iterate through file and convert color info to 8-bit integer:
file.scan(/sfa:[rgb]=\"(\d\.?\d*)\"\s+sfa:[rgb]=\"(\d\.?\d*)\"\s+sfa:[rgb]=\"(\d\.?\d*)\"/) do |w|

  r = (w[0].to_f*255).to_i
  g = (w[1].to_f*255).to_i
  b = (w[2].to_f*255).to_i
  puts "<div style=\"width:100px;height:100px;float:left;background:rgb(#{r}, #{g}, #{b});\">&nbsp;</div>"
end

puts "</body></html>" # close html
```

After pruning duplicate lines, this is the visual result of the process.

[image: color palette]

These colors are used in the default Showroom layout. You can now select (one click) the **individual** same-colored areas of a bar graph (here: grey or red).

In the graphics inspector ([image: graphics inspector]) you can change the colors according to your wishes. Pick the colors from above graphic with the color picker like this:

[image: color picker magnifying glass]

Comment: Wow, cool, but can you select this color for a chart? Because it standard chart color options I didn't see ones

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this helps!